# How to get a tensorflow variable under certain namescope?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose we want fetch a value of a tensorflow variable ,we can just run it under a session.

Suppose `a = tf.Variable(...)`

Then its value can be fetched using `sess.run(a)`

But if there are two variables with same name but different name scope, how do I fetch the value of individual variables?

```
with tf.name_scope("x"):
      a = tf.Variable(...)
with tf.name_scope("y"):
      a = tf.Variable(...)
```

Then how do I get values of `a` under `x` and `a` under `y` respectively?
If I do `sess.run(a)`, I am getting value under name_scope `y` (recent one)

Comment: Not familiar with tensorflow, but this looks like a Python issue not a tensorflow one: when you assign a, the original value is lost, regardless of the context in which it's assigned. You'll probably have to use a different variable under the other name scope. I'd suggest `x_a` and `y_a`.

Comment: You are deliberately shadowing the previous variable `a`. What's the point of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout names of vars and get them by scope/names:

```
with tf.variable_scope("x"):
    a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=1)

with tf.variable_scope("y"):
    a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=2)

with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    [print(var.op.name) for var in tf.global_variables()]
    res = s.run(['x/a:0', 'y/a:0'])
    print(res)
```

returns:

```
x/a
y/a
[1, 2]
```